# Is there a concrete date when event.getDefaultPrevented() will be removed?

Tags: javascript, firefox, mozilla

I have a large project with more than 1 million LOC, and I'm trying to prioritize the conversion from `getDefaultPrevented` to `defaultPrevented`.  I noticed that it has been deprecated several years and am curious how soon it will finally be removed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to answer that. Maybe a good way to get a realistic answer could be to ask people in the [bug 691151](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=691151), the bug that was filed about the removal.

It looks like all the code depending on `getDefaultPrevented` [was removed](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/search?q=getDefaultPrevented&redirect=false) from mozilla-central and the site compatibility documentation was [updated recently](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2015/event-getpreventdefault-will-be-removed/) about that as well.

I would not bet on the removal taking much longer.